# Triple Point of a compound and critical point

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, experimental-chemistry, equilibrium, phase

Is it necessary for all compounds to have a triple point? Also, how is the triple point determined?

Suppose a substance does not have a triple point, so how do researchers agree on the impossibility of existence of a triple point in such a case? Also, can there be multiple triple points for a compound?

Also, since the vapour equilibrium curve ends at point E, what is the phase of water beyond that point?

[image]

Comment: All compounds except helium have a triple point, unless they decompose before reaching it. As for the second question, the phase beyond E is called supercritical fluid.

Comment: So what is the phase of water in supercritical fluid?

Comment: The phase **is** supercritical fluid. To call it a liquid would be wrong. To call it a gas would be wrong too.

Comment: Imagine analogy: There is a beach(liquid) and a steep cliff plateau above it (gas). when you walk along the shore ( heating up), the beach  climbs up and the cliff plateau goes down, each becoming more similar to the other. At some point ( critical point ) they meet and become the same.  Is it a cliff or a beach ?

Comment: @Poutnik Yes,I get you, each deriving properties of the other with also remaining itself... it could be anything depending on P,T and other values.

Comment: It is evidence you have not got it yet. Their ALL property values converge to each other. Imagine a fog and a foam, each under intensive mixing, where you gradually add water or air respectively, at some point, there is no difference between fog and foam.

Comment: Do you mean to say there is no distinction between both and they become same eventually ,meaning there is no vapour nor liquid  ?

Comment: Exactly. If you mix 1 kg of substance and 1 kg of identical substance in identical state, what you get ?

Comment: Something which is not either of them but all over same (homogeneous sort of)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121266/discussion-between-poutnik-and-pv).

Comment: @IvanNeretin - helium does have a triple point where the liquid (He-I), superfluid (He-II), and gas phases meet. It is at 2.17 K and about 0.03 bar. Just not the 'normal' triple point, but 3 distinct phases coexist there.

Comment: @JonCuster That's right, point taken.

Comment: @Poutnik "Is it a cliff or a beach ? "        depends:are you at sea level? ;)

Comment: @buckthorn Not, you are not. :-)  It was said the beach slowly climbing ( or is prolonged ) and cliff does the otherwise. As some point, there is no cliff in the sense of an edge.

Comment: @buckthorn Another analogy could be a skipping gramophone groove, where the skip is the ordinary phase transition, while the plate rotation is going around the triple  point to do the same phase transition again and again. Like only evaporation and no condensation. Or vice versa.

Answer (score 5):

The essential condition is the compound thermal stability.
If it decomposes below its melting point, it does not have a triple point.
If it decomposes before properties of gaseous and liquid phases converge to each other,  it has just estimated, extrapolated triple point.

Beyond CP we talk about supercritical fluid, it kind of shares many properties of both liquid and gaseous worlds.

It is usually determined experimentally, or as an extrapolation.

See the picture of liquid/gas phase system below, at and above the critical point on [Wikipedia: Critical_point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(thermodynamics))

Answer (score 1):

You must first understand what happens when water is heated along the boiling curve.
Start from the point $\pu{100°C}$and $\pu{1 atm}$. At this point there are two phases, one liquid whose density is nearly $\pu{1 g/cm^3}$ and exactly $\pu{0.96 g/cm3}$. And the vapor has a density of $\ce{0.0006 g/cm^3}$. If now you heat this system in a closed volume, the temperature and the pressure will increase like in a steamer. But the densities of the two phases vary in opposite directions. The liquid expands, and the vapor contracts.

At $\pu{180°C}$ , the liquid has a density of $\pu{0.87 g/cm3}$ and the vapor $\pu{0.0079 g/cm3}$

At $\pu{312°C}$, the liquid has a density of $\pu{0.71 g/cm3}$ and the vapor $\pu{0.046 g/cm3}$

At $\pu{374.8°C}$, both the liquid and the vapor have a density of $\pu{0.32 g/cm3}$

If you look at the surface of the liquid just before $\pu{374.8°C}$, the surface of the liquid gets less and less visible. It is transformed into a sort of haze, and slowly disappears. Of course the pressure is extremely high ($\ce{217 atm}$) and the curve pressure vs temperature stops at $\pu{374.8°C}$.